# Installing water utility network in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, installation

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

I cannot install water utility network in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

I did not find "infrastructure editing toolbar" application.

Where can I find this?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 is ancient software, long retired. It cannot utilize modern, supported extensions.

Comment: I need "valve isolation trace". There is no solution for it in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0??

Comment: There's certainly no supported solution.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are trying to use the [Water Geometric Network Editing and Analysis](https://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/network-editing/) solution which is part of ArcGIS Solutions for Water:

> Water Geometric Network Editing and Analysis requires specific technical experience and software

including

> ArcMap (Standard or Advanced) 10.2.1, 10.4 - 10.7

Consequently, it appears that your ArcGIS Desktop version is not recent enough to use this solution.